# Is there any software like voipgain,  megavoip,  poivy?

Tags: software-recommendation, voip

Is there any software like voipgain, megavoip, poivy ? With this software I used to talk to many countries,especially in Bangladesh at low cost when I used Windows 7.

But now I'm using Ubuntu and I cannot use this software. Can you please help me about these voip software. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Skype is available, as it Jitsi

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> then `sudo apt-get install skype`

http://jitsi.org/index.php/Main/DebianRepository

Answer (score 1):

Try Ekiga, it supports many voip providers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @qbi. The tag was `software-recommendation` and `voip` and the question is 'Is there any software like voipgain, megavoip, poivy ?'. I could not understand what you mean.